# Opening specific applications on startup of windows in specific windows 10 desktops

Tags: windows-10

On startup I want that Windows 10 loads Firefox into Desktop 1, Anki into Desktop 2 and Evernote into Desktop 3.

How do I set this up so that the process happens automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add FF, Anki and Evernote to  `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Now for all three program do following steps:

1. Open the application.
2. Re-size the window so that it is not maximized or minimized.
3. Move the window to the monitor you want it to open on by default.
4. Close the application.  Do not re-size prior to closing.
5. Open the application.
   It should open on the monitor you just moved it to and closed it on.
6. Maximize the window.

The application will now open on this monitor by default. If you want to change it to another monitor, just follow steps 1-6 again.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the Windows 10 _Virtual Desktop_ feature, not to (physical) monitors.